# Unzip a file into a target directory?

Tags: macos, zip

I have a file called `All CRGs.zip` and I want to unzip its contents into a directory called `data` (which already exists and has some other files in).

Is this possible? I'm working on OSX.

I've tried:

```
$ unzip "All CRGs.zip" -d data/
```

But this unzips everything into `data/All CRGs` which is not what I'm looking for. I'd like everything to go straight into `data`.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm sure it would have been easier to just double-click it, let it extract to it default location [normally right next to the .zip] then drag the contents over to the new location.

Comment: I think you can change `data/` to simply `data` and it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either recreate the **complete** folder-structure including the `All CRGs`-Folder or you can ommit **all** folders inside the ZIP-file by using the `-j`-flag for the unzip-command.

The problem is that the ZIP-file has been created using the `All CRGs`-Folder as top-level like `zip "All CRGs.zip" "All CRGs"`. The correct way would have been `zip "All CRGs.zip" "All CRGs/*"`which would have created a ZIP-Archive of all the files and folders inside the `All CRGs`-folder **without** the surrounding folder.

So the only way to extract only the files by retaining the folder-structure would be something like this:

```
unzip "All CRGs.zip" -d data/ && mv "data/All CRGs/*" "data/" && rmdir "data/All CRGs"
```

It will unzip the complete folder and after that move the content of the folder up one level and finaly remove the (now empty) "All CRGs"-folder.

Comment: "The correct way would have been..." doesn't match with my expectation. I tried creating a zip file using that syntax and I get "name not matched". If I take `All CRGs/*` out of the quotes, the files get added to the zip, but with the parent directory present.

Comment: There have been at least 2 new Versions of OS-X (macOS) since that question was answered. So there might have been a change. What Version of macOS are you working on?

Comment: Good point. 10.12.5 is the latest version and the version I was using at the time of this comment.

Comment: the `mv` command will not move the hidden files. an additional `mv "data/All CRGs/.*" "data/"` is required.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the zip file contains an unwanted top-level folder, and since you know the name of that top level folder, you can use a symlink to cause all the contents of that folder to appear in the parent like so:

```
ln -s . 'data/All CRGs'
unzip 'All CRGs.zip' -d data
```

The `ln` step causes the folder `data/All CRGs` to be created, linking to the current directory (relative to `data/`), which is `data/`. Then, when you extract files from `All CRGs.zip` and the `unzip` command tries to create `data/All CRGs/file.dat`, that file will get created as `data/./file.dat`.

This technique can be demonstrated without a zip file using touch:

```
$ mkdir data
$ ln -s . data/subdir     
$ touch data/subdir/foo.txt
$ ls data
foo.txt subdir
```

You can use this trick too to cause certain files or folders to be extracted to an alternate folder:

```
ln -s /tmp data/subdir2
```

Then anything in the archive being extracted to `subdir2` will appear in `/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Keka](http://%20%60https://www.keka.io/en/%60), free on mac. Click on the ZIP and choose the directory to extract into

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for MacOS unzip command is to unzip the file into the current directory. From `man unzip`:

> The default behavior (with no options) is to extract into the current
> directory (and subdirectories below it) all files from the specified
> ZIP archive.

So if you `cd data` and run `unzip "All CRGs.zip"` the contents of the zip file will be extracted into the `data` folder. `Unzip` will prompt you for any name collisions before overwriting.